# PHPExcel Radar Chart Main Axis Missing

Tags: phpexcel, radar-chart

I want to use phpexcel to draw a radar chart, but when I open the generated file with Microsoft Excel 2010, the chart's main axis is missing(like below image, the first is wrong, the second is correct).

[The wrong chart draw by phpexcel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU2sk.png)

[The correct chart draw by Excel 2010](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOw3Z.png)

Then I read phpexcel's examples '33chartcreate-radar.php', but it has the same problem.

How do I make the main axis show?

```
$excel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setTitle('sheet');

$data = [
    ['Direction', 'N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE', 'S', 'SW', 'W', 'NW'],
    ['Frequency', 10, 20, 5, 10, 15, 30, 5, 5]
];

$sheet->fromArray($data, null, 'A1');

$dataseriesLabels = array(new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String',
    'sheet!$A$2', NULL, 1));
$xAxisTickValues = array(new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String',
    'sheet!$B$1:$I$1', NULL, 8));
$dataSeriesValues = array(new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String',
    'sheet!$B$2:$I$2', NULL, 8));

$series = new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries(
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::TYPE_RADARCHART,
    null,
    range(0, count($dataSeriesValues)-1),
    $dataseriesLabels,
    $xAxisTickValues,
    $dataSeriesValues,
    null,
    null,
    PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeries::STYLE_MARKER
);
$plotarea = new PHPExcel_Chart_PlotArea(null, array($series));
$legend = new PHPExcel_Chart_Legend(PHPExcel_Chart_Legend::POSITION_TOPRIGHT,
    NULL, false);
$title = new PHPExcel_Chart_Title('Wind Rose Diagram');
$chart = new PHPExcel_Chart(
    'chart1',
    $title,
    $legend,
    $plotarea,
    true,
    0,
    null,
    null
);
$chart->setTopLeftPosition('A7');
$chart->setBottomRightPosition('I32');
$sheet->addChart($chart);

$ExcelWrite = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel, "Excel2007");
$ExcelWrite->setIncludeCharts(true);
$ExcelWrite->save('D:\TestRadarChart.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 0):

If Excel vba is OK, I could display it.

> ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).hasMajorGridlines=true

1. Select the target chart on excel.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> on excel, then VBE opens.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> on VBE, then immediate window opens.
4. Paste the above code.
5. Place the cursor on the line of the code and press the enter key.

I made the file with PHPExcel and edit it with excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about side effect, but it may be possible to fix it.

I confirmed with PHPExcel 1.8.0.

source:

```
Lib/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Chart.php(450)
```

before:

```
$objWriter->startElement('c:axPos');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', "b");
$objWriter->endElement();
```

after:

```
$objWriter->startElement('c:axPos');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('val', "b");
$objWriter->endElement();

$objWriter->startElement('c:majorGridlines');   //added
$objWriter->endElement();                       //added
```